# For which n, m natural numbers with zero the function $\sqrt{x^{2m} +y^{2n} }$ is differentiable at the origin

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> For which n, m natural numbers with zero the function $\sqrt{x^{2m} +y^{2n} }$ from  $\mathbb{R} ^2$ $\rightarrow$ $ \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at the origin

What I could show is that the function is differentiable for $(m,0),(0,n), (0,0)$ and is not differentiable for $m=n \neq 0$ at the origin. Any hints about the other $(m, n)$?

Comment: Isn't this the drevative for the expression? $\frac 1 2 (x^{2m} + y^{2n})^{\frac {-1} 2} (2m \cdot x^{2m-1} + 2n \cdot y ^{2n-1} \cdot \frac {dy}{dx})$

Comment: @AnasKhaled No. OP is asking about the multidimensional derivative.

Comment: My mistake question was unclear

Comment: Are you sure that $f$ is not differentiable for $m=n=2$?

Comment: No I'm not sure

Comment: @Iwan5050 "No I'm not sure" That's why in this forum we ask people to post their own work on the problem. We can't see what you have done. For all we know all the cases you say you can do could be incorrect. Please, share what have you done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m, n\in \mathbb N$.

**if $n=m=0$**: $f(x,y) = \sqrt 2$ which is clearly differentiable at $0$.

**if $n > m=0$** (similar to $m > n=0$): $$f(x,y) = \sqrt{1+y^{2m}}$$ which is clearly differentiable at $0$

**if $n \ge m > 1$** (similar to $m\ge n > 1$):

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y) - f(0,0)}{\left\|(x,y)\right\|} &= \lim\limits_{r\to 0} \frac{r^{m}\sqrt{\cos(\theta)^{2m} + r^{2(n-m)}\sin(\theta)^{2n}}}{r}\\&=\lim_{r\to 0}r^{m-1}\sqrt{\cos(\theta)^{2m} + r^{2(n-m)}\sin(\theta)^{2n}} = 0
\end{align}

This proves that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and $\partial f(0) = (0,0)$.

The only remaining case is $n \ge m=1$ (similar to $m\ge n=1$): $$f(x, 0) = \left|x\right|$$ which is not differentiable at $0$ and $f$ will not be differentiable at $(0,0)$